# Redundancy in web API

Tags: xml, api, http

I am reviewing a simple XML API to be used over http and was wondering if having data redundancy is a good thing or not.

```
<Items num_items="3" total_cost="10.00">
    <Item id="3" cost="3.00" />
    <Item id="6" cost="5.00" />
    <Item id="7" cost="2.00" />
</Items>
```

Is `num_items` and `total_cost` useful in ensuring data integrity, or is it just pointless fluff?

Answer (score 0):

Only you can make that decision, based on the system requirements which you've not shared.  If it's critical that the `Items` element contain a specific, predetermined number of items and it's possible for that to be not true in the real world, then you should include `num_items` and have an explicit definition for what to do if they don't match.  If it's not important, don't complicate things.